# how to do json parsing for url which has no parent and child node name

Tags: android

How I do json parsing for this url
url="http://reeldealsantikosapi.staging2.perpetuating.com/ReelDealServices.svc/POS/GetDatesForTheater2?TheaterId=7";

```
enter code here
try {
            // Getting Array
            JSONArray  j= json.getJSONArray(jResponse);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = j.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("val of c  " +c);
                // Storing each json item in variable




            }

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jResponse);
        if(Global.showTimes.size()<=0){

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(jsonarray.get(i));

        }
        }



 tv.setText((CharSequence) Global.showTimes);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("exception" +e);
    }
```

Comment: can you please post json response string ?

Comment: URL is available in question,just paste in browser